# Struct will not work when contained in header files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, directx, header-files

So I have three concerning files:

```
MyGame.cpp        //Where all my codeing takes place
MyDirectX.h       //Where I declare prototypes
MyDirectX.cpp     //where I define functions/structs
```

I have a nice little struct that looks like this:

```
struct Sprite
{
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture;

int frame;
int starttime;

    Sprite()
    {
        texture = NULL;
        texture = LoadTexture("explosion_30_128.tga");
        frame = 0;
        starttime = 0;
    }
};
```

So Here's the problem:

The struct works just fine when I declare it in MyGame.cpp. However, I need it in my header files because other functions depend on it (and for tidiness sake). I declare it in MyDirectX.h as such:

```
struct Sprite;
```

And define it in MyDirectX.cpp:

```
struct Sprite
{...code...};
```

I can create a global Sprite in MyGame.cpp

```
Sprite explosion;
```

And all checks out. But when I try to explosion.frame = or explosion->frame = (or any other members for that matter) I get the error "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type."

If I define the entire struct in MyDirectX.h and not MyDirectX.cpp I get an unresolved external symbol. If I define in both I get a redefinition error.

I've been doing tests and researching for hours and I just can't figure this one out. It makes no sense to me why the struct would work in MyGame.cpp but not work when I use it in my header files. I should note that that I've declared and defined many functions in these files and they all work just fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.
 Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I think I can come up with something.

Comment: "I can create a global Sprite in MyGame.cpp" No you cannot, not with the setup you've described: http://liveworkspace.org/code/28MHuK$1 You must make the _definition_ visible at the point where you use the type in a manner which requires a complete type.

Answer (score 4):

`Sprite sprite;` is a **definition**, not a declaration. It attempts to create that object. To declare the class, just add `struct Sprite;`.

To have a global, you'll need to use `extern Sprite sprite`, otherwise, you'll get a multiple definition error when including that header in multiple translation units.

Comment: Opps, that was a typeo in my question, not my code. I did declare it as struct Sprite.

Comment: Your answer is still relevant after some 7+ years! Yours and another one I found on another answer page of a similar question really shed some light on the difference between definition and declaration and how pointers work with that. Thank you! Sau mai bine spus "Multumesc!"

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the full definition of the `struct` in a header so it can be accessed by whatever code the complete type:

```
struct Sprite
{
  LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture;

  int frame;
  int starttime;

  Sprite();

};
```

You can then put implementation code in a separate `.cpp` file. For code that doesn't need the full type, you can continue to use a forward declaration

```
struct Sprite;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type." means that you have only forward declared an object, but not provided a definition, hence "incomplete".

Forward declaring, i.e.

```
struct Sprite;
```

Lets you:
1) store/pass a variable as a Sprite*
2) store/pass a variable as a Sprite&

You can't do anything else, i.e. call functions or access members of the Sprite.

To do those things you need the definition, which is the

```
struct Sprite
{
  LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture;

  int frame;
  int starttime;

  Sprite();
```

};

So if another .cpp file is using a Sprite, you will have to put the definition in a header and include that header in the .cpp using sprite.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had tried that earlier but it looks like I miss read the error that came with it. May be a another issue completely. But just to clarify, structs should be declared and defined in the same .h file rather then split up into a .h and a .cpp file like functions?

Comment: Generally structs are not split up into .h/.cpp files, because structs usually don't have functions, or if they do, they are really short and can just be put inside the struct definition.

Comment: If the struct is only used in one cpp file, then you can define the struct in that same cpp file.  If its used in two or more cpp files, you must put the struct definition in a header file and include it in the cpp files.